# sed to search between two patterns and append text at the end of search result only

Tags: sed

Here is my file (test.txt):

```
start
line1
line2
line3
end
```

I want to search all the lines between the patterns **start** and **end** and then append "<" at the end of the searched lines. The final output should be (need an inline replacement in the same file):

```
start
line1<
line2<
line3<
end
```

I also want to do an inline replacement in the same file. Here is what I have done till now.

```
sed -n '/start/,/end/{/start/!{/end/!p;};}' test.txt
```

This gives me the below output:

```
line1
line2
line3
```

But I don't know how I can do the inline replacement in the same line. I tried this but it does not work.

```
sed -n -i.bkp '/start/,/end/{/start/!{/end/!p;};}; s/$/</' test.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```sh
sed -i.bkp '/start/{:a;N;/end/!s/$/</;/end/!ba;}' test.txt
```

*Details*:

- `/start/` - matches a line containing `start` and then executes the subsequent block of commands...

  - `:a` - sets an `a` label
  - `N` - reads the next line appending it to pattern space
  - `/end/!` - if there is no `end` in the current pattern space...
  - `s/$/</` - replace end of string position with `<` (adds `<` at the end of the pattern space)
  - `/end/!ba` - if there is `end` stop processing block, else, go to `a` label.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/fSiTGu):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s='start
line1
line2
line3
end'
sed '/start/{:a;N;/end/!s/$/</;/end/!ba;}' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
start
line1<
line2<
line3<
end
```

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i '/start/,/end/{//b;s/$/</}' file
```

Select the range between `start` and `end` and if it is neither of the two regexps denoting the range, append `<` to the end of each line.